# Chrome/brave use the wrong keyboard layout

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, brave

I have a Spanish laptop with an English UK USB keyboard attached.
I've configured PC UK keyboard in Ubuntu settings and everything work perfectly...

... except Chrome/Brave which have the " and @ transposed.

Any ideas where Chromium browsers store their view of what the keyboard payout is?

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard                                                                                                                           
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc104alt"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="compose:ralt,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: @Quasímodo same result. Keyboard still behaves like a US keyboard. In case it's significant, each keystroke causes a log message "Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_user_time called on non-toplevel"

Comment: Could you post the content of `/etc/default/keyboard`?

Comment: @Quasímodo tried the suggestions, no change. My chrome is installed from dpkg, not snap (because my home diris not under /home). I've pasted my /etc/default/keyboard into my question. Thx for looking into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed

I did two things. I haven't yet figured out which worked.

In Ubuntu_settings/keyboard

1. I added a second keyboard layout and then toggled to the new, then back to the original
2. I changed from "use the same source for all windows" to "switch input sources individually for each window"

Answer (score 0):

Settings → Languages → Preferred languages and select *Add Languages* and add *English United Kingdom* to match your keyboard in use.

Use the 3 vertical dot icon to select *More actions* and select *Move to the top*.

Comment: thx but my Chrome (and Brave) are already set to Language/PreferredLanguages=Englush(United Kingdom).
I'm not sure that this language setting is relevant for keyboard layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe create/change layout that those apps use. Not sure if it works in Wayland, but in older X11 I was always editing and creating layouts in /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/**